# How to save changes to existing excel file instead of creating a txt file with the changes?

Tags: excel, vbscript, save

My code reads column B from the excel file and removes values that have any underscore at the end of the character and then save it to a new txt file with the changes. But now I would like it to save whatever changes that the codes does(remove underscore) in the existing excel file and overwrite it instead of creating a new txt file with the changes... help pls anyone?

```
'********** Declare the Output Values **********

Dim v_Parent, v_Child, v_Alias

Dim v_Output2 

Dim c_Delimiter, c_Max_Length, c_Underscore, c_Comma


'********** Declare the Shell, Directory & File Properties **********

Dim objShell, objShell2, objFile


'********** Declare the Excel Properties **********

Dim objExcel, objWorkbook


'********** Declare the Other Variables **********

Dim c_Char

dim row

c_Underscore = "_"
c_Char = 1
c_B2 = "B2" 
c_FirstWksht      = 1

Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set objFSO2 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objWorkbook2 = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("D:\Shared\tempname\test\test2.xlsx")
          Set objFile = objFSO2.CreateTextFile("D:\Shared\tempname\test\test2.txt")

          '********** Instantiate the Workbook.Worksheets **********
          '               object to open a particular
          '                    Excel Worksheet
          Set objWorksheet2 = objWorkbook2.Worksheets(c_FirstWksht)

            set Description_column_n = objWorksheet2.Range(c_B2).EntireColumn

            For row = 1 To (Description_column_n.Rows.Count - 1)
            v_Output2 = Description_column_n.Cells(row,1).Value

             Do while (Right(v_Output2, c_Char) = c_Underscore)
               v_Output2 = left(v_Output2, len(v_Output2) - c_Char)

               Loop
            objFile.Write v_Output2 & vbCRLF 
            next



            Set objWorkbook2 = nothing
             objExcel.Quit


                    '********** Exit the Script **********

                    Wscript.Quit
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps surprisingly, you would [save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197585%28v=office.15%29.aspx) the workbook:

```
...
objWorkbook2.Save
objWorkbook2.Close

objExcel.Quit
```